# Easiest way to determine the index of a child element relative to its parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some HTML markup, similar to:

```
<div id="parentElement">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

I am attaching an event handler to each child element with jQuery:

```
$( "div.child" ).on( "click", someFunction );
```

Is there an easy way for me to figure out which child element was triggered/clicked from the event object?   For example, I'd like to be able to determine if the user clicked on the 3rd child `<div>` versus one of the other child `<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[currentTarget](https://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/)** property of the event object or use **jQuery's** **[index()](https://api.jquery.com/index/)** function.

```
$( "div.child" ).on( "click", function(event){
   console.log(event.currentTarget);
} );
```

```js
$("div.child").on("click", function(e) {
  console.log(e.currentTarget);
  console.log($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentElement">
  <div class="child">First</div>
  <div class="child">Second</div>
  <div class="child">Third</div>
  <div class="child">Fourth</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/)** method to get index based on its siblings and inside the handler `this` refers to the dom object of clicked element.

```
$("div.child").on("click", function() {
  console.log($(this).index())
});
```

```js
$("div.child").on("click", function() {
  console.log('Clicked div' + ($(this).index() + 1))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentElement">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery `.index()` function on the clicked element.

```js
$( "div.child" ).on( "click", function(e){
  alert($(this).index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentElement">
    <div class="child">Test1</div>
    <div class="child">Test2</div>
    <div class="child">Test3</div>
    <div class="child">Test4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [**index**](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to find the index of child

```
$( "div.child" ).on( "click", function(event){
console.log($(this).index())

} );
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ee4vrht4/)